# Trying to call Jquery plugin method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fuelux

I am using ["Fuelux Tree"](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#tree) jQuery plugin for generation tree view. And try to get selected items via jQuery method `selectedItems` which described in [this](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#tree) document. But I have no idea how can I call this `SelectedItems` method

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. It works. @Zabavsky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain selected items like this:

```
var selectedItems = $('#MyTree').tree('selectedItems');
```